# Safety group on tanked water heater

Tags: water-heater

I have recently installed a tanked water heater. I have installed the safety valve that was inside the package, at the cold water inlet.

Something strange happened yesterday. The city cut the water supply for some time, and I noticed my water meter running backward, at very high speed. So it seemed like water was flowing OUT of my house.
I also noticed at a different time that the inox pipe leading to the cold water inlet was actually hot.

So I wonder if I have a problem with my safety valve on my water heater. Here's how it looks:

[image: My safety device]

When I look on the internet, safety group actually look bigger:

[image]

Is the device I installed a proper safety group?
Is there a chance that this device does not prevent the water from flowing back from the tank to the cold water circuit?

Comment: What you need is a vacuum breaker, which prevents siphoning the water heater tank. What you show is unclear - the "stock picture" looks like a tempering/thermostatic valve, perhaps, but unlike the ones I've seen in having that valved port, and the thing you installed looks more like a temperature/pressure relief that should typically be installed directly on the tank. Perhaps it's pressure relief only, if instructions were to install on the cold inlet.

Comment: What make and model is said water heater?

Comment: If it is an electric water heater and the tank water level dropped, then the heating elements might be burned up and need replacing.

Comment: What country are you in? It makes a difference. I'm guessing, but what you have installed looks like a drain valve. Also TPR (Temp/pressure relief) valve are installed on top of the WH, at least in the USA.   If you are worried about this happening again, a simple check valve on your cold inlet would prevent backflow.

Comment: Where I live in Pennsylvania, all incoming service water lines must have a "back flow preventer" installed so that what you describe will never happen. Also most outdoor faucets must also be so equipped to prevent a back flow that could contaminate the water supply when a hose is attached.  That device you showed in the picture is not a safety valve.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. I do think it is a pressure relief valve. I think it stops the back flow a little bit, but not enough.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I think that's right, it's pressure relief only. I think this does a little bit of backflow preventing, but maybe not enough

Comment: I very much doubt it has ***any*** backflow prevention function. Pressure relief (only) I'd believe.